# Fetch data from database in a tree structure in sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

In my application I have a tree structured table and I want to know that if I can fetch the tree structure data from sqlite database by simply applying a single query. Currently I am lopping it manually using a for loop and able to meet my requirement but I am not statisfied with that approach as its more complex, may be time consuming, etc.

My table table structure is as below,

```
parent_id |  cat_id

  null    |   1
   1      |   2
   1      |   3
   1      |   4
   4      |   5
   4      |   6
```

So, now above is my table structure and I want to fetch the tree structure like,
If I pass parent_id as `1` in my query then it should return `2,3,4,5,6` as `1` is parent of `1, 2, 3, 4` and `4` is parent of `5,6` and also `4` is child of `1`

So, input and output expected by me,

```
input    output

  1     2,3,4,5,6
  4     5, 6
```

So, it there a simple way to acheive the above tree structure by using sqlite query?

**OR**

There is no way to acheive this using sqlite query and I need to follow the current method or way that I am using it by manually looping all the category ids.

Comment: i am not sure but, use group by using `parent_id` and then use `group_concat` to concat `cat_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any solution from sqlite itself, so created an Algorithm that creates Tree structure by iterating over each id & over its sub_ids and write into database.

I had gone through [Closure Tables](http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html) which gives the expected result that I was looking as a solution

Some more references of Closure Table -

http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html
http://karwin.blogspot.in/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use group_concat method as it is available in sqlite.

For your question i have created one table called `Trans` and added `parent_id` and `cat_id` columns.

```
select parent_id, group_concat(cat_id) from trans group by parent_id;
```

I have table like this i have mentioned below.

[image]

and i got resultant like this :

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I had already tried this way. This only gives the immediate sub_cat_id, not the sub to sub_cat_id!